# How to get rid of handler dragging delay?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml

There's a range slider implementation. The problem is that when I press on a handler and start dragging, it doesn't move for a moment, therefore it happens some delay and distance between a handler and a mouse cursor.

[image]

```
Image { // handler's implementation
    id: handler1
    // ...

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: parent
        drag.axis: Drag.XAxis
        drag.minimumX: -width
        drag.maximumX: handler2.x - parent.width
        onPositionChanged: {
            slider1 = (max - min) * (handler1.fakeX) / root.width + min
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me how to deal with it?

Comment: Did you try changing the value of `drag.threshold` in your `MouseArea` ?

Comment: @dydil, yup, `drag.threshold: 0` really works. Thanks. You can post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `drag.threshold` property of your `MouseArea` to 0 so that dragging starts immediately.